# ListView checkboxes are over text, how to pad text and force checkbox standard color?

Tags: java, android, xml

I have a listview checkboxes with text in a Linear Layout:

```
<CheckBox android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/nomeAPP" style="?listItem" />
```

But those checkboxes are over the text.

There's any way to pad the text a little to the right?

Also, I was testing with a AVD with 2.2 SDK. Just tested on my phone (also on 2.2), but looks like because of the phone theme (i have a cooked rom) the checkbox color is white (instead the standard grey). Is anyone way to force the checkbox color to the usual grey?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the padding attribute i.e `android:paddingRight` to apply padding to text towards right.Please refer this [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android%3apaddingRight).

Comment: You mean paddingLeft ;)

android:paddingLeft="8mm" works just fine!

Comment: Yes I mean padding on both side either right or left works fine.As per your question you asked about right padding.It is better to use `dp(density independent pixel)` or `sp (scale-independent pixel)` instead of `mm`.